# Skype4Com how to login?

Tags: c#, skype4com

Hi i created small project using Skype4COM, and it works, but first i need to open my skype and login. My question is if this is possible to login into skype using this library ?

Comment: Here is a link to a [Relevant Article](http://community.skype.com/t5/Desktop-API-former-Public-API/skype4COM-login/td-p/242464).

Comment: @Noob seems that this is impossible it is not allowed with the public API Term of use, see section 3.6: http://www.skype.com/intl/en/legal/terms/api/ because to get this information, you would need to prompt the end-user for it, which is not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what your developing you could go the whole mile and develop a whole UI with Skype integrated into it.

See skypekit for more info: http://developer.skype.com/public/skypekit

Allen smith
 I work for Skype developer and am a Microsoft employee.